How to display a custom page when accessing http://ex.com:443 with nginx
Access to https://ex.com works fine.
However, when accessing http://ex.com:443,
I want to show a custom error page, but it does not work or an error occurs in nginx.conf.
The error.html works under normal circumstances, but it does not seem to work when a request is made to port 443 without a certificate when SSL is in effect.
nginx version : 1.22.1
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
http{
    server{
        # Not working or error when nginx -s reload

        listen 443;
        error_page 400 /error.html;
        
        location = /error.html{
            root /app;
            internal;
        }
    }


    server{
        # It works here.

        listen 443 ssl;
        
        server_name ex.ex.or.kr;

        error_page 400 /error.html; # Not working
        
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/a.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/b.pem;
        ssl_session_tiemout 5m;
        
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:MEDIUM:!SSLv2:!PSK:!SRP:!ADH:!AECDH;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        

        # Not working
        location = /error.html{
            root /app;
            internal;
        }
        
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80/;
            proxy_redirect off;
                                                
        }
    }
}


Nginx can listen on a port with or without the SSL protocol - it cannot do both at the same time.

Thank you for answer. So, what should I do to customize the Nginx 400 page when accessing "http:/ex.com:443"? Simply error_page 400 /error.html; This does not apply.
